# Leverage IoT SDK in module, propagate to device

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I have a scenario where we have devices that can communicate via MQTT, but it is not possible to use the C SDK on them. I'd like to use the SDK in a edge module instead, and the edge module is responsible for intercepting device twin changes, and then using MQTT send them to the correct device.

I'd like for it to work like a transparent gateway, but the gateway will offload the need for the device to implement the SDK and simply know of a contract that we decide beforehand.

Is this possible? Is it a bad idea? Should I simply implement the parts of the SDK I need straight on the device instead?

Comment: Let me clarify a few things before I post an answer.  1) Can you share more details on why you cannot use the C SDK on the leaf devices?  Is it due to size constraint?  If so, please share the specification of the leaf devices.  2) In the scenario you are describing, the identity of the leaf devices is created in the module.  Hence you are looking at an identity translation scenario (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway).  This is definitely possible.  How many leaf devices are connected?

Comment: Identity translation is exactly what I'm after. I've read all the documentation but I still don't understand how the edge module is supposed to do this. The transparent gateway is the simplest scenario and the only one that is documented. Regarding the SDK, the chip is simply too limited. It has a pre existing API using sockets that we'd like to leverage. The number of devices is pretty small, ranging in the hundreds in different regions at the moment I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles over this, we resolved it in a satisfactory way.

Downstream leaf devices connect to a module gateway and present their credentials. The module sends the credentials to the IoT Hub using a `ProvisioningDeviceClient`. The module is then responsible for handling the returned `DeviceClient`, and if a direct method or twin update is detected, the module propagates the change or method request to the leaf device using the appropriate transport method. In our case, this is either SFTP or sockets.